# Android cannot update SurfaceView in onCreate()?

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

What i'm trying to do, is to create a drawing app, with a SurfaceView. My app is basically done, but one thing is missing: I cannot get the SurfaceView to draw itself in the onCreate of its activity.

My `SurfaceView` derived class looks like this (just the important parts):

```
class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements OnTouchListener
{ 
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    public DrawingSurface(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
    }
    // this method does the painting.
    public void paint()
    {
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        //draw a bunch of stuff
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    //in the onTouch method i call the paint() without any problem
}
```

And the onCreate of the Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    surface = new DrawingSurface(this);
    setContentView(surface);
    //surface.paint(); <--- here is the problem
}
```

So as you can see the code is pretty standard, but if i try to use the surface.paint() in the onCreate(), then i get a `NullPointerException`, because at that time, the `SurfaceHolder` returns null for the `lockCanvas` call.

So how can i solve this problem? I want this paint method to run at the beginning of the Activity, because otherwise the background only gets painted, when the user starts drawing. What i tried:

- Placing the `surface.paint()` in the `onResume()` - same result.
- Overriding the surfaces `draw(Canvas)`, and draw there - no luck.
- Doing a nullcheck on the Canvas before drawing - no exception but,
  nothing gets drawn, just like without surface.paint() in the
  onCreate()

I have really no idea, why this happens, otherwise everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different model. Do all the painting inside the SurfaceView

```
public class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public DrawingSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
        updatePanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        updatePanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        updatePanel();
    }

    public void updatePanel() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (getHolder()) {
                doDraw(canvas);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd also call the updatePanel method in your touch listener.

All your painting goes in the doDraw method, which is never called outside the SurfaceView. Also, be sure you do a null check in the doDraw on the Canvas object before trying to draw anything.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, but i was actually doing the drawing in the SurfaceView. Eclipse doesn't even offer me these functions to override, when i look at the list. What classes parts are these methods?

Comment: Sorry, I left out an important piece of info. Those methods belong to SurfaceHolder.Callback. Implement that and set the surfaceView as its own callback in the constructor.

Comment: Hero of the day :D Thank you very much!!